# How do i assign roles to a user fetched from my database in symfony 4?

Tags: symfony

I'm a newbie to symfony 4.2. and trying to create an authentication form to access a back-end. I am not using FosUserBundle.
So far i have an a access denial due to that the user has not admin permissions.

in my user table created with make:user, i have a column named "roles" which contains an empty array.
I guess it should contain something like 'ROLE_ADMIN' but i have no idea.

Any help is welcome. Thanks

Comment: It's up to you to build the interface (Web Form or CLI Command) in the application and update the database entity`$testUser->setRoles(['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN']); $em->flush();`.

Comment: @fryefrye : do you mean i have to make a fixture ?

Comment: No, a fixture would be used in testing or initial loading of an application's data. Symfony does not come out of the box with the commands or forms to update user roles for you. They leave it up to the developers to create their desired functionality. This is why `FOSUserBundle` is so popular. As it provides a lot of the missing desired functionality for user management. Providing things like `php bin/console fos:user:promote testuser ROLE_ADMIN`, that a basic install of Symfony does not.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look to the official documentation : https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html

The column `roles` is an array in Doctrine, so serialized string in database, you can fill this with :

```
a:1:{i:0;s:10:"ROLE_ADMIN";}
```

This way your user will have admin role. Then you can manager the roles access in your `security.yml` file, according to documentation.

Comment: For me, using Doctrine, the column mapping is set as [`json_array`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/basic-mapping.html#doctrine-mapping-types), and the resulting database value looks like `["ROLE_ADMIN"]`